# Looking for a abstract algebra book for at the advanced undergrad/early grad level that does not assume prior exposure

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for an abstract algebra book that covers groups, rings, and fields at an advanced level. I am coming from Baby Rudin and Axler's linear algebra book but have not taken any prior courses. I have heard Dummit and Foote, Fraleigh, and Herstein are the standard options but I know there are videos from Harvard and lecture notes from MIT corresponding to Artin's book and looking at the table of contents it seems very extensive. I have heard of Lang's undergraduate book but have not heard anything good nor bad about it so am not sure. I have also heard of Lang's and Hungerford's graduate books but am unsure if they would assume previous exposure? What have you either learned or taught from and what would y'all recommend.Thanks!

Comment: @notananalyst Looks interesting. It seems to explore a lot of category theory. What other fields in math use categories?

Comment: To my knowledge, all algebraic areas of mathematics use category theory to some extent, but even in areas of mathematics with a more analytical flavour, category theory is useful for keeping things straight, and seeing mathematics in a more holistic way.

Comment: Artin's book is a far more interesting, advanced undergraduate text. Although you already know linear algebra, he weaves linear algebra into the story throughout the text.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely check out Aluffi's "Algebra : chapter 0", it's a good book, quite extensive, with pretty much no prerequisite. Lang's book called "Algebra" is probably just as extensive (in all fairness, Lang's book might even cover a bit more than Aluffi's), but in my opinion very unfriendly and hard to read, especially if it's your first approach. I can't say much about the other book you mention, I haven't used them as much or at all (except maybe Dummit & Foote, which is nice as well, but I'd still pick Aluffi over D&F).

Comment: I think Aluffi is a very good book. I found the first chapter to be fairly difficult, since all of the categorical notions take some getting used to (especially since there are few examples that the author has available). However, once you get through the first chapter, things become easier, and the categorical notions start to feel more intuitive and concrete. I think Lang's book is a good reference book, but to try to read it from start to end would be absurd.

Comment: oh right I definitely forgot Aluffi's book starts with a tiny bit of category theory. So I definitely agree with your comment, although I would add that it ends up being a nice bonus, because getting comfortable with category theory "early on" might turn out to be quite useful in the end :). Completely agree with you about Lang : it's a great reference once you're familiar with the subject, but fairly terrible to learn from at first.